# Why are my extrinsic parameters generated by solvePNP so different from the source parameters?

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

I have a stereo camera, where each camera has a focal length of 2000 pixels (approximately), and independent principal points. If I estimate the relative pose and calculate extrinsic parameters (assuming camera 1 is at `t=0|R=I`), I can triangulate observed features to come up with a 3D point estimate.

As a test, I run my observations and points through opencv's solvePNP routine. I expect to get the same results as those that I estimated above. Instead, however, I get a vastly different resection.

My question is, why does solvePNP generate a result with such a large disparity from the original pose?

Things to note:  My initial intrinsic and extrinsic parameter estimates are very rough (not from calibration). This should affect my results, but I would have expected the triangulated results to reflect my contrived parameters.

```
K = [2221, 0, w/2; 0 2221, h/2; 0 0 1]
```

Comment: Probably made a mistake somewhere. Try passing 3D-2D correspondences from the camera 1 as a basic test and see if you get the identity pose back. At least show us your intrinsics matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed, the solvePNP of the camera located at world origin resolves to a completely different location. Do you have any suggestions as to what input data might be incorrect (I would post the code, but it is too large for a stackoverflow question)?

Comment: I have the same problem... Anyone can help?`